# Using switch power supply to simulate battery presence on a solar inverter

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have a bunch of solar panel feeding an inverter/charger, but I don’t have batteries, so when the AC load is too high, the whole thing shuts down..

[image]

So the idea is to plug a switch power supply to replace the battery to provide temporary lack of solar power. The PSU is giving me 24.1 V without load, and at minimum possible setting, the inverter will start trying to charge the “battery” with it goes under 24 V. Can I add a diode or something to protect the PSU in case the inverter sends it charging current?

Comment: What’s your AC load? How much current can your 24 V SMPS source?

Comment: it's quite miscellaneous, but under 3KW. The SMPS is capable of delivering 50A. If the combined power of solar + SMPS is not sufficient for the load, the inverter automatically shut down (which is fine)

Comment: If the power supply is set slightly higher than a fully charged battery (24.1V is probably too low), the inverter shouldn't try to charge it. Lower might work depending on the inverter. Nonetheless you can easily block reverse current by adding a diode in series.

Comment: If your SMPS can deliver enough power, it could be that 24.1 V us simply too low as for what the inverter is concerned and triggers UVLO. A 24 V battery won’t be happy below say 24.3 V.

Comment: In the settings menu of the charger/inverter, I have set the trigger if battery charging to the minimum, which is 24.0V. Can I count on a diode in series to prevent damage on the SMPS ? What specific kind of diode ?

Comment: The SMPS would cost more than an appropriate battery. /boggle at why everyone is always trying to find a way to avoid batteries.  They don't bite!  Just two lead-acids or three modules from a Nissan Leaf gen1.  $200-ish either way.

Comment: Well I bought this second hand 50A SMPS for 60 bucks, it doesn't contain lithium, cobalt or lead, and it's lifespan is not intrinsically limited. Also it never gets empty..